# how to split equation using a macro

Tags: macros, equations, split

i want to slpit an equation using only a macro: 
here the code i used :

```
\[\begin{split} 0=E_{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\zeta^s M_{t,t+s}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\right)P^{\circ}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(j)^{-{\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}}}\left( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}}-\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)\left(-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\right)\left( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\textbar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}-1}\end{split}\]
```

[image]

Comment: (1) always make full mwes, not just sniplets, makes it a lot faster for others to help. (2) please explain " don't want to use begin equation and end equation with split here the code i used", since `\[...\]` is the same as `equation*` and `equation` does not support line breaks, what exactly do you want?

Comment: i want to break a long and non numerated equation using a macro ( \[...\])

Comment: splitting into lines and equation numbering are more or less unrelated, and more or less everything in tex is a macro, what do you mean by "split using a macro"? Your question would be a lot clearer if you posted a usable example, and stated what output you wanted from that example.

Comment: i just want to split a non numerated equation into two lines

Comment: You cannot split a `\left[...\right]` construction. You need to scale manually. Then it can be broken

Answer (score 7):

`split` doesn't break the equation by itself: the user should choose the alignment points and the breaks.

Here's an example, where I suggest a shorthand for a complicated expression that is very long and becomes unreadable in exponents. You can choose a different name from “A”, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

We can write the following equation
\[
\begin{split}
0 = E_{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\zeta^s M_{t,t+s}
    &\biggl[
      (1-A(z,t,s))
      P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)^{A(z,t,s)}
      \Bigl(\frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}\Bigr)%
        ^{A(z,t,s)}
\\
    &\quad- \mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)A(z,t,s)
    \Bigl(
      \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s}
      \bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}
    \Bigr)^{A(z,t,s)-1}
    \biggr]
\end{split}
\]
where
\[
A(z,t,s)=-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for coming up with the `A(z,t,s)` term to simplify the equation.

Comment: @Mico One of your favorite devices. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using a `split` environment doesn't seem right here as there are no natural alignment points across the rows. Instead, I would a single `multline*` environment.

To improve the legibility of some of the terms, I would use infix fraction notation in the exponent terms. I would also get rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives and replace them with `\Biggl`, `\biggl`, `\biggr`, and `\Biggr` as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'multline*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*} 
0=E_{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\zeta^s M_{t,t+s} \\
  \times\Biggl[
  \biggl(1-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr)
  P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)^{-1/(1+p^{z}_{t+s})}
  \biggl( \frac{1}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}
     ^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}\biggr)^{\!-1/(1+p^{z}_{t+s})}\\ -\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)
  \biggl(-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr)
  \biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)}{\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \bar{\Pi}^{1-\theta} P_{t-1+s}}\biggr)
     ^{\!-1/(1+p^{z}_{t+s})-1}
  \,\Biggr]
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant, with more readable exponents, and `\overline` instead of `\bar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\let\sst\scriptstyle

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{split} 0=E_{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\zeta^s M_{t,t+s}\left[%
\biggl(1-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr)P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)^{-{\frac{\sst 1}{\sst 1+p^{z}_{t+s}}}}\Biggl( \frac{1}{ \rule{0pt}{2.2ex}\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}\Biggr)^{-\frac{\sst 1}{\sst 1+p^{z}_{t+s}}}\right. \\%
  \left. -\mathcal{MC}_{t+s}(j)\biggl(-\frac{1}{1+p^{z}_{t+s}}\biggr)\Biggl( \frac{P^{\circ}_{t+s\bar{t}}(j)}{\rule{0pt}{2.2ex}\Pi^{\theta}_{t-1+s} \smash{\overline{\mathstrut\Pi}}^{1-\theta}_{\phantom{1}} P_{t-1+s}}\Biggr)^{-\frac{\sst 1}{\sst 1+p^{z}_{t+s}}-1}\right]\end{split} \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The opening square bracket in row 1 looks to be smaller than the closing square bracket in row 2. Is that an optical illusion? Also, the `(1-\theta)` superscript terms next to `\overline{\Pi}` seem to be placed very differently from the `\theta` superscript terms associated with `\Pi`. Any way to keep the superscript terms at a consistent height? Finally, did you verify that the two-line equation fits inside the (default) width of the textblock?

Comment: @Mico: Measuring the square, I find a small difference (~ 0.5pt). This is due to the different contents of both lines, and using pairs like  `\left[ \right.`. I think it's more of an optical illusion. Not sure it's perceivable in a printed version. For the `\theta` exponents, I've modified the code. And, yes, it fits within margins.

Comment: Loading the `geometry` package alters the default width of the text block, doesn't it? :-)

Comment: I'd say it produces more sensible margins, unless you use margin notes. If one wants wide margins, one can play with `aligned` on 3 lines and `\MoveEqLeft` for the 1st line.